# using custom WSGIRequestHandler while running Flask application with uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, werkzeug

I'm running Flask app with custom request handler in development setting and it works just fine. However I can't find info about how to run Flask app with custom request handler in production mode (like with uWSGI for example).

In development mode I run my app like this:

`app.run(threaded=False, processes=12, request_handler=CustomWSGIRequestHandler)`

How to use CustomWSGIRequestHandler when running my app with uWSGI?